# How to display data according to Package like Platinum,Gold,Silver in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

In Package table which is Tbl_Package I have columns PackageID,PackageName,Orderno.
For Platinum Orderno is 1,for Gold it is 2,Silver 3.
I have another table for Patients Tbl_Patientinfo in which I have columns PatientID,PatientName,
PackageID,PackageName .
According to Package patients should be displayed in platinum all platinum member patients should be displayed,In gold all gold member patients so on for silver my query is below

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[Sp_Get_AppointmentRequest_Data]
as begin
select a.PatientID,a.PatientName,b.PackageID,b.PackageName,b.Orderno from Tbl_Patientinfo as a 
left join Tbl_Packageinfo as b on a.PatientID=b.PackageID
order by PatientID desc
end
```

and in my view

```
<h2>Platinum</h2>
<div class="sparkline8-graph">
                        <div class="static-table-list">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="headings">
                                        <th class="column-title">SNO</th>
                                        <th class="column-title">Patient Name</th>
                                        <th class="column-title">Package</th>
                                        <th class="column-title">Mobile</th>
                                        <th class="column-title">Address</th>
                                        <th class="column-title">Date</th>
                                        <th class="column-title">Manage</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    @{
                                        if (Model.PatientList == null || Model.PatientList.Count() == 0)
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="color: #ff0000;">No results found!</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            foreach (var item in Model.PatientList)
                                            {
                                                <tr class="even pointer">
                                                    <td class=" ">@item.RowNumber</td>
                                                    <td class=" ">@item.PatientName</td>
                                                    <td class=" ">@item.PackageName</td>
                                                    <td class=" ">@item.Mobileno</td>
                                                    <td class=" ">@item.Address</td>
                                                    <td class=" ">@item.Date</td>
                                                    <td class=" ">
                                                        <a href="@Url.Action("Patientinfo", new { @id = @item.PatientID })" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit </a>
                                                        <a href="#" id="Del" onclick="DeletePatientinfo(@item.PatientID)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Delete </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

for gold and silver same as above 
How should i Display patients separately according to package?

Comment: Assign the Patients with a PackageId and then use Where clause like  ```PackageId = 'Platinum'``` to fetch them

Comment: and in view how should i bind? @NoobCoder

Comment: Create a new variable (a list) in your model class and iterate into it

Comment: Can you help with the query I'm unable to get what you said

Comment: i have to fetch with Orderno @NoobCoder

Comment: Can you specify your db structure of the related tables

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching all member from the table, If you want to filter only platinum member from fetched record and display in razor view, You can set the condition

```
 @foreach(var item in Model.PatientList)
    {
@if(@item.PackageID == 1)
{
   <tr class="even pointer">
      <td class=" ">@item.RowNumber</td>
      <td class=" ">@item.PatientName</td>
      <td class=" ">@item.PackageName</td>
      <td class=" ">@item.Mobileno</td>
      <td class=" ">@item.Address</td>
      <td class=" ">@item.Date</td>
      <td class=" ">
      <a href="@Url.Action("Patientinfo", new { @id = @item.PatientID })" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit </a>
      <a href="#" id="Del" onclick="DeletePatientinfo(@item.PatientID)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Delete </a>
  </td>
</tr>
}
    }
```

Comment: how should i fetch dynamic name like for platinum records heading name should be packagename platinum and it should be dynamic @Dip Surani

Comment: just like we filter packageID
@foreach(var item in Model.PatientList)
{
 @if(@item.PackageName= "platinum")
  {
  }
}

Comment: It should be dynamic for example package name as heading then all records under that package name,heading platinum then all records of platinum under it likewise for any packagename @Dip Surani